# why google earth distance between two points and haversine/Vincenty great-circle distance formula not providing same distance

Tags: geometry, gis, geo, google-earth

[image]
I was calculating the distance between 2 points using google earth Ruler and **haversine**/**Vincenty great-circle** distance formula BUt result is not getting the same how can I get the same result as per google earth?

```
  function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  echo 'haversineGreatCircleDistance: '.$angle * $earthRadius;
}
haversineGreatCircleDistance( 22.098299, 90.394299,26.564095, 88.408258);

function vincentyGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
  $a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) +
    pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);
  $b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

  $angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);
  echo 'vincentyGreatCircleDistance: '.$angle * $earthRadius;
}
vincentyGreatCircleDistance( 22.098299, 90.394299,26.564095, 88.408258);

 function twopoints_on_earth($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom,$latitudeTo,  $longitudeTo)
      {
           $long1 = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
           $long2 = deg2rad($longitudeTo);
           $lat1 = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
           $lat2 = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
             
           //Haversine Formula
           $dlong = $long2 - $long1;
           $dlati = $lat2 - $lat1;
             
           $val = pow(sin($dlati/2),2)+cos($lat1)*cos($lat2)*pow(sin($dlong/2),2);
             
           $res = 2 * asin(sqrt($val));
             
           $radius = 3958.756;
             
           return (($res*$radius)*1609.34);
      }
       // latitude and longitude of Two Points
      $latitudeFrom = 22.098299 ;
      $longitudeFrom =  90.394299;
      $latitudeTo = 26.564095;
      $longitudeTo =  88.408258;
      // Distance between Mumbai and New York
      print_r(twopoints_on_earth( $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom,$latitudeTo,  $longitudeTo));
```

Comment: What EXACT locations are you using in your example?  The coordinates in the code do not match neither Mumbai nor New York, the distances do not match the given coordinates.

Comment: Using Vincenty formula, the distance between 22.098299N 90.394299E and 26.564095N 88.408258E is 534105.868 m.  Using the most advanced and ridiculously accurate Karney algorithm I'm getting 534105.867687 m.

Comment: can you show me that using this  22.098299, 90.394299,26.564095, 88.408258  coordinate?

Comment: Use this Vincenty formula calculator:
https://geodesyapps.ga.gov.au/vincenty-inverse
Select "WGS84" and "Geographic" reference system.

Comment: BTW, harversine formula assumes the Earth is a sphere, it is simple, but delivers approximate results.  Vincenty formula is the gold standard, it uses a proper ellipsoid.

Comment: @Thinko thank you I am trying to make PHP function for it I was checking your example that is an amazing result.